# Apache HttpClient: Correct Way to Measure Response Time

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-commons-httpclient

I'm trying to measure the server response time using the Apache HttpClient. I have set up the test code below. I assume that tp3 shows the (send-to-receive) time. In the test below tp3 = 198.13ms. According to Google Chrome the server response time is 17ms (181.13ms quicker).

Am I missing something?

What is the best way to measure the server response time with the Apache HttpClient?

```
     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        long tp0 = System.nanoTime();

        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        long tp1 = System.nanoTime() - tp0;

        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://example.com");
        long tp2 = System.nanoTime() - tp0;

        CloseableHttpResponse response1 = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
        long tp3 = System.nanoTime() - tp0;

        long tp4 = 0;
        long tp5 = 0;
        long tp6 = 0;
        long tp7 = 0;
        StatusLine resp;

        try {
            resp = response1.getStatusLine();
            tp4 = System.nanoTime() - tp0;

            HttpEntity entity1 = response1.getEntity();
            tp5 = System.nanoTime() - tp0;

            EntityUtils.consume(entity1);
            tp6 = System.nanoTime() - tp0;

        } finally {
            response1.close();
            tp7 = System.nanoTime() - tp0;
        }

        System.out.println("tp1 = " + fmt(tp1)); //tp1 = 611.26ms
        System.out.println("tp2 = " + fmt(tp2-tp1)); //tp2 = 3.16ms
        System.out.println("tp3 = " + fmt(tp3-tp2)); //tp3 = 198.13ms
        System.out.println("tp4 = " + fmt(tp4-tp3)); //tp4 = .01ms
        System.out.println("tp5 = " + fmt(tp5-tp4)); //tp5 = .00ms
        System.out.println("tp6 = " + fmt(tp6-tp5)); //tp6 = .91ms
        System.out.println("tp7 = " + fmt(tp7-tp6)); //tp7 = .01ms

        System.out.println("Response = " + resp);

    }

    private static String fmt(double val){
        val = val / 1e6;
        DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###,###.00");
        return formatter.format(val) + "ms";
    }
```

Comment: Methodology is the same as any another prase of code. You can use [Google Caliper](https://github.com/google/caliper) library if you interested in  micro benchmarking. Anyway if you need to mesure average response time - use special load testing tool like LoadRunner or JMeter, and stop reinventing the wheal.